# Identify apps installation from shareit

Tags: firebase, google-play, google-analytics-firebase

Is it possible to identify apps installation from shareit or not using firebase or google analytics data?

I want to understand how much my apps installed from shareit using firebase data or gplay data

Answer (score 0):

You could consider checking first_open conversions. It doesn't directly track app install, it is only logged when a user opens the app for the first time after installation.

Though, Firebase can only track campaigns from supported Ad Networks listed [here](https://firebase.google.com/products/analytics/partners/). And it looks like Share It is not a supported ad network. With that, you may still track conversions by creating a [custom campaign](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317518?hl=en#custom) and include the UTM values in the campaign URL (e.g. utm_source=shareit) by using [Firebase Dynamic Links](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/). Firebase can automatically detect this source and will attribute the conversion to "shareit".